# My Xcode is coming up with this error when I try to build "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'HomeHeader_Previews' conform to 'View' "

Tags: swiftui, static-methods

I am not sure what In the code I need to chnage to make the build successful. Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum Tab {
    case home,message,calender,profile
}

struct TabBarItem: View {
    let selectedImage: String
    let unSelectedImage: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    let action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            VStack {
                Image(isSelected ? selectedImage : unSelectedImage )
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Theme.primaryColor : .secondary)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

struct TabView: View {
    @Binding var tabIdx: Tab

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            TabBarItem(selectedImage: "ic_selected_home", unSelectedImage: "ic_unselected_home", isSelected: tabIdx == .home) {
                self.tabIdx = .home
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            TabBarItem(selectedImage: "ic_selected_message", unSelectedImage: "ic_unselected_message", isSelected: tabIdx == .message) {
                self.tabIdx = .message
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            TabBarItem(selectedImage: "ic_selected_calendar", unSelectedImage: "ic_unselected_calendar", isSelected: tabIdx == .calender) {
                self.tabIdx = .calender
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            TabBarItem(selectedImage: "ic_selected_profile", unSelectedImage: "ic_unselected_profile", isSelected: tabIdx == .profile) {
                self.tabIdx = .profile
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 30)
        .frame(height: 80)
        .background(
                 Rectangle()
                      .fill(Color.white)
                      .shadow(
                          color: Color.gray.opacity(0.2),
                          radius: 15,
                          x: 0,
                          y: 0
                       )
        )
    }
}

struct BottomTabBar: View {
    @State var tabIdx: Tab = .home
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            switch tabIdx {
                            case .home:
                                HomeHeader_Previews() *This is where the error comes up*
                            case .message:
                                MessageHistoryView()
                            case .calender:
                                ScheduleView()
                            case .profile:
                                ProfileView()
                            }
                
                    TabView(tabIdx: self.$tabIdx)
                    
                 }//:VStack
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
    
}

struct BottomTabBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BottomTabBar()
    }
}
```

The build was working when Xcode was on iOS 14 but I guess because it's iOS 15 something needs to be changed? If you can help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know what more I need to change to make the code work or maybe if I should change it back to iOS 14 but I don't know how.

Comment: It’s a typo somewhere. Comment out section until the error reveals itself

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS 14 or 15. iOS 17 is the current version of iOS assuming you are using Xcode 15.x.

Answer (score 1):

In your `BottomTabBar` I assume `HomeHeader_Previews()` is a `PreviewProvider`.

Don't put a `PreviewProvider` inside a View body, use only other Views. This is the reason for your error. `PreviewProvider` is just to provide preview for Xcode.

Try using the view, such as `HomeHeader()` in your `BottomTabBar`